# How to set two identical y-scales in the same graph in Labview?

Tags: graph, labview

When a graph is very wide I want to show the y-axis values also on the right side of the graph so it becomes easier to read the corresponding values of the lines.

I know how to duplicate the left axis to the right. And when the graph is created I use *ActYscl* to set the range of scale nr 0 (left) to scale nr 1 (right). This works when the graph is created and also the zoom and pan function work on both y-scales. However, when I use the Autoscale function of the *Graph Pallet*, only the initial axis is scaled (probably because the graph data are only linked to the original axis).

Is there a way to make the autoscale function work for both y-axis at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Charts and graphs have an `Autoscale Range Change` event. Use an event structure to catch this event and update the range of the duplicate scale to match the first one:

[image: chart on front panel]

[image: VI snippet (drag on to your VI diagram)]

I've used a chart for this example as it's simpler, but it should work the same for a graph. Of course you need a way of telling the event loop when to exit; I've used the `Value Changed` event of the `stop` button. If your application uses an event-driven structure anyway, you should just be able to add the autoscale event to your existing event loop.

Comment: Thnx, this is exactly what I needed.
I use a graph and works likewise. As I plot the graph in a new VI window I use the _Panel Close_ event handler to stop the loop.